# QueryDsl orderBy specific string values

Tags: java, spring, sorting, jpa, querydsl

I need to sort my database response by three different strings. 
Field can take only those four values `"A", "B", "C", null`. 
Is there a way to ***sort data in custom defined order*** while retrieving it from DB **using QueryDsl**?

```
customOrder = ["B", "A", "C"]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution is to assign numbers to cases using `CASE` and sort those numbers with `ASC/DESC`.

Solution in SQL:

```
SELECT *
FROM table
ORDER BY CASE 
   WHEN field = 'B' THEN 1,
   WHEN field = 'A' THEN 2,
   WHEN field = 'C' THEN 3
   ELSE 4
   END
```

Solution:

```java
private OrderSpecifier<Integer> provideStatusOrder() {
        NumberExpression<Integer> cases = new CaseBuilder()
                                                  .when(field.eq("B"))
                                                  .then(1)
                                                  .when(field.eq("C"))
                                                  .then(2)
                                                  .when(field.eq("A"))
                                                  .then(3)
                                                  .otherwise(4);
        return new OrderSpecifier<>(Order.ASC, cases);
}
```

Usage:

```java
return query.orderBy(provideStatusOrder())
            .fetch();
```