# QueryDsl orderBy some enums and date

Tags: java, spring, sorting, jpa, querydsl

I need a way to sort based on date, with all rows of a certain type to be grouped last (but also sorted by date).

For instance, suppose I have a DB column where values can take on ["A", "B", "C"]. In the same table, there is also a dateCreated column.

I want all rows with "A" to be last and all rows (including those within group A) to be sorted by date created (ascending for simplicity sake)

For instance, if I had the rows:

| ID | enum | dateCreated |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | A | 2020-01-01 |
| 2 | A | 2020-01-03 |
| 3 | A | 2020-01-02 |
| 4 | B | 2020-02-03 |
| 5 | B | 2020-02-01 |
| 6 | C | 2020-02-02 |

The resulting order should be:

```
5,6,4,1,3,2
```

To explain, all of the non-A rows come first, ordered by date. Then all of the A rows, also ordered by date.

I see the SO post [QueryDsl orderBy specific string values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67447083/querydsl-orderby-specific-string-values) which almost provides what I need, but it is unfortunately not nuanced enough for my use case.

Comment: Sounds unlikely - how would you communicate that A is special,  but I don't know. If not possible, as an alternative is it worth  wrapping your query interface in another class that sorts the list that comes back based on your nuanced rules?

Comment: Oh I see - my bad, you can implement OrderSpecifier, and so in theory you can do whatever you need there, but I guess you're wondering how to do that for your case, I haven't looked in detail at that interface but I'd expect it to be pretty flexible in terms of how complex your ordering can be

Answer (score 2):

I ended up finding a working solution with something like:

```
    private OrderSpecifier<Integer> orderByEnum() {
        NumberExpression<Integer> cases = new CaseBuilder()
                .when(QTable.table.enum.eq("A"))
                        .then(2)
                .otherwise(1);
        return new OrderSpecifier<>(Order.ASC, cases);
    }
```

I added that to a order specifier array like so:

```
    OrderSpecifier<?>[] order = new OrderSpecifier[] {
            orderByEnum(),
            QTable.table.dateCreated.asc()
    };
```

And then I passed the order specifier array to the query with

```
    queryFactory.select(...)
            .from(...)
            .where(...)
            .orderBy(order);
```

It looks like this got me what I needed. Just had to break the problem down into individual components and add that to an order specifier array.

Answer (score 0):

You can order by a boolean expresion. Booleans order false to true naturally, so you can just sort ascending.

```
.orderBy(enum.eq("A").asc(), created.asc())
```

Comment: hmm I'm getting an exception: "org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QuerySyntaxException: unexpected AST node..." maybe I'm doing something wrong here.

Comment: Ah I believe you must use a predicate instead of an boolean expression here. Do you have the full error?